# Overridden member not serialising properly

Tags: c#, xml, xsd.exe

My `xsd.exe`-generated classes aren't serialising exactly how I want them to.  Can anyone tell me how to get `InterestInProperty` to appear in the serialised version?

The generated classes are too long (14,000 lines of C#) to post here, but I'll try to show the relevant excerpts.  For reference, [here is the full schema](https://ws.valex.com.au/lixi/schema/).

I want one chunk to serialise to this:

```
<FullRegistered ValSubType="Standard" ReasonFor="FairMarketValue" InterestInProperty="FeeSimpleInPossession">
    ...
</FullRegistered>
```

but it's actually serialising to this:

```
<FullRegistered ValSubType="Standard">
    ...
</FullRegistered>
```

For the time being let's assume that the solution for serialising `InterestInProperty` will apply to `ReasonFor`.

Here's the `ValuationType` class, which contains the `FullRegistered` item:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ValuationType
{
    private Identifier[] identifierField;
    private object itemField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Identifier")]
    public Identifier[] Identifier
    {
        get { return this.identifierField; }
        set { this.identifierField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Costing", typeof (Costing))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FullRegistered", typeof (FullRegistered))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProgressInspection", typeof (ProgressInspection))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RestrictedAccessAssessment", typeof (RestrictedAccessAssessment))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WorkFlow", typeof (WorkFlow))]
    public object Item
    {
        get { return this.itemField; }
        set { this.itemField = value; }
    }
}
```

Here's the abridged definition of `FullRegistered`:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class FullRegistered
{
    private FullRegisteredInterestInProperty interestInPropertyField;
    private bool interestInPropertyFieldSpecified;
    private FullRegisteredValSubType valSubTypeField;
    private FullRegisteredReasonFor reasonForField;
    private bool reasonForFieldSpecified;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public FullRegisteredInterestInProperty InterestInProperty
    {
        get { return this.interestInPropertyField; }
        set { this.interestInPropertyField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool InterestInPropertySpecified
    {
        get { return this.interestInPropertyFieldSpecified; }
        set { this.interestInPropertyFieldSpecified = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public FullRegisteredValSubType ValSubType
    {
        get { return this.valSubTypeField; }
        set { this.valSubTypeField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public FullRegisteredReasonFor ReasonFor
    {
        get { return this.reasonForField; }
        set { this.reasonForField = value; }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool ReasonForSpecified
    {
        get { return this.reasonForFieldSpecified; }
        set { this.reasonForFieldSpecified = value; }
    }

}
```

And the `FullRegisteredInterestInProperty` enum:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public enum FullRegisteredInterestInProperty
{
    CrownLeasehold,
    FeeSimpleInPossession,
    ACTLeasehold,
    LeaseholdInterest,
    Lessors,
    Lessees,
    SharesInCompany,
    SubjectToLongTermLease,
    Timeshare,
    UnitsInTrust,
    Other,
}
```

Comment: Private variables will not serialize.  Make then public.

Comment: @jdweng, the private fields are in fact backing fields for public properties such as `public FullRegisteredInterestInProperty InterestInProperty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown how you're populating the properties, but I'm going to guess that you've ignored the `xxxSpecified` properties that are related to the two properties that don't serialise.

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Another option is to use a special pattern to create a Boolean field recognized by the XmlSerializer, and to apply the `XmlIgnoreAttribute` to the field. The pattern is created in the form of *propertyNameSpecified*. For example, if there is a field named "MyFirstName" you would also create a field named "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs the XmlSerializer whether to generate the XML element named "MyFirstName".

So, if you want `InterestInProperty` and `ReasonFor` to be serialised, you need to set the generated `InterestInPropertySpecified` and `ReasonForSpecified` properties to `true`.

Comment: Your assumption that I wasn't setting xxxSpecified was correct.  And now that I am, it serialises nicely.  Many thanks.